# How to change desktop picture with transition

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

For example, fading from picture a to b with a cross-fade for the entire desktop picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do this with static images. However, a hidden feature discovered a long time ago lets you [run a screen saver as your desktop background](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/set-screen-saver-to-desktop-background.html). You could use one of the built-in screen savers under the Pictures category to achieve this.

Comment: As far as I can tell it's not really doing anything with the background itself aside from setting it. Looks like it's using a custom window at desktop level to perform the fade effect, then gets rid of it when it's done. Do a "strings ./DeskLickr.app/Contents/MacOS" and you can see the evidence of this.